# how to fix "TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'"

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a python file that will spam a directory with .txt files.

I decided to start working with Tkinter but whenever I try to input a number I get this error message `"TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'"`

The code I am working with is:

```py
from tkinter import *  

top = Tk()  

top.geometry("400x250")  

Amount = Label(top, text = "Amount").place(x = 30,y = 50)  

def spam():
    for i in range(int(e1)):
        print(i)

sbmitbtn = Button(top, text = "Submit",activebackground = "pink", activeforeground = "blue",command=spam).place(x = 30, y = 170)  

e1 = Entry(top).place(x = 80, y = 50)  



top.mainloop()
```

I've tired switching the 
`for i in range(int(e1)):` to 
`for i in range(str(e1)):` 
but then I get the error message:

```
"TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"
```

Any help is good help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `get()` method to get the value of the Entry. Example:

```
def spam():
    for i in range(int(e1.get())):
        print(i)
```

And don't place/pack the entry in the same line:

Wrong:

```
e1 = Entry(top).place(x = 80, y = 50)
```

Correct:

```
e1 = Entry(top)
e1.place(x = 80, y = 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first get the value inside the entry and then cast it to integer.

```
def spam():
  entry_val = e1.get()
  for i in range(int(entry_val)):
    print(i)
```

Comment: okay so i've updated my code to what you have given me but now i ge the error
"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'"